# Is coffee maker the same as coffee server?

Tags: vocabulary, word-difference

These are the images when I did google searches:
[image: coffee server] coffee server
[image: coffee maker] coffee maker

Does it mean the server is part of the maker?

Answer (score 1):

A

> **coffee maker**

can be thought of as the piece of equipment used to ***make*** or ***brew*** the coffee.

In your example, the

> **coffee server**

is the vessel used to deliver the brewed coffee especially of the coffee is brewed in a large urn.  On many occassions, the coffee is ***brewed*** into a vessel, the **coffee pot** which can then be used for serving (your Mr Coffee is an example).

Comment: So it means the server is the pot, right?

Comment: In your example, yes, the *server* is the pot, and *often* coffee is served directly from the coffee pot in which it was brewed, unless it's drip filtered or pressed.

Comment: @user67265 Note, however, that a "server" may *also* be a person who delivers coffee to somebody else—such as in a restaurant. The same word can be used to describe both the container of the liquid and the agent of the delivery. it depends on what you're referring to.

Comment: @JasonBassford Got it.

Answer (score 0):

No. Coffee makers usually include a coffee server when you purchase them. They just complete each other and sometimes they are sold separately.